# Mesh follows parented armature correctly, but only half way

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-weights

I have a vertex group that I've weight painted to follow the rotation of a deformation bone.  As I rotate the bone, the mesh follows the rotation correctly, but the vertices with a value of 1.0 only appear to be moving at 50% of the bone's rotation, and the vertices at lower weights even less.

The deformation bone's Y axis is rotated 140 degrees off of the global axis, and it pivots on its local X axis.  This might explain the problem, but I don't know the solution.

Comment: if they move only 50% it means that they are also part of another vertex group with an equivalent weight of 1

Comment: I think moonboots is right: the vertices have been accidentally assigned to two groups in entirety, so they are averaging between the two respective bones.

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem.  Noobie mistake!